# How to get the last 3 created objects from the database?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-filter

I want to display the last 3 created objects onto my website. I have no clue what to do. 
I just need to know how to order the model according to created date. And, access the 1st, 2nd and 3rd item of the ordered set.

I'm pretty sure this doesn't work. This is from views.py

```
latest = Upcoming_Events.objects.all().order_by('date')[:3]

event1 = latest.get(pk=1)

event2 = latest.get(pk=2)

event3 = latest.get(pk=3)
```

I keep getting

> 'Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken'

Answer (score 3):

You can make ORM like this

```
latest = Upcoming_Events.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]
```

Then in template

```
{% for event in latest %}
    {{ event.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**
As per comment try this

```
event1 = latest[0]
event2 = latest[1]
event3 = latest[2]
```

Comment: Actually the template features 3 different animations for each event. So I can't have a for loop running. I need event1, event2 and event3 to be separated.

Answer (score 1):

make a descending order on pk(id)

```
latest = Upcoming_Events.objects.all().values().order_by('-id')[:3]
```

then:

```
event1 = latest[0]
```

***UPDATE***

Notice that you have to use `.values()`.

If you do not use it the SQL Query will not contain `LIMIT 3`